# how to use Groupby and iloc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

My df is of stock price. Following is list of column head of my df.

```
['Date',
 'Open',
 'High',
 'Low',
 'Close',
 'Volume',
 'Dividends',
 'Stock Splits',
 'Scrip',
 'Low/Close',
 'High/Close',
 'Cls/Cls',
 'Vol/Vol',
 'VolSMA3',
 'VolSMA5',
 'VolSMA7',
 'VolSMA10',
 'TTQ/VolSMA3',
 'TTQ/VolSMA10',
 'Month_Yr',
 'Year',
 'Month']
```

I tried:

```
schyr = schaeffler.groupby(['Month_Yr']).agg({'Open':[schaeffler['Open'].iloc[0]],'High':['max'],'Low':['min'],'Volume':['mean','var','max','min']})
print(schyr)
```

Expectation: When I use `groupby` with `Month_Yr` I want `Open` price at start of every month i.e first trading day of month and `Close` price at end of every month i.e last trading day of every month.

Comment: don use iloc and use `first` and `last`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [NamedAggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) and the `first` and `last` functions:

```py
schyr = schaeffler.groupby("Month_Yr").agg(
    Open=("Open", "first"),
    High=("High", "max"),
    Low=("Low", "min"),
    Close=("Close", "last"),
)
```

This means create a new aggregation by `Month_Yr` where:

- `Open` is the first Open of the group
- `High` is the max High of the group
- `Low` is the min Low of of the group
- `Close` is the last Close of the group

Comment: How to add scrip name to the resultant df.

Comment: If `Scrip` is some type of a security identifier, you can add it to the `groupby` function